Change "bounty ended" to "bounty awarded" in answer's timeline & revision history
Over the lifecycle of an awarded bounty, four events occur in the question's timeline (and revision history): "notice added", "bounty started", "notice removed", "bounty ended". These accurately reflect what happened from the question's perspective. In addition, one event occurs in the answer's timeline (and revision history): "bounty ended".
That's rather confusing from the answer's perspective. The bounty didn't just "end"; it was awarded to that answer. In addition, from the answer's history, this mysterious bounty never started. The bounty just appears out of thin air, finishing. I certainly was confused to see a bounty "ended" on an answer of mine since bounties can't be started on answers. After being thrown for a moment, I figured the the only way for a bounty to end on an answer was for it to be awarded to that answer, but that's because of information I had outside of the timeline/revision history.
It would be more correct and clear if the event was recorded as "bounty awarded" or similar for the answer. (Granted, this is significantly less confusing for the revision history, since the longer description there includes "X reputation awarded by", but that text isn't in the timeline.)
